# Hide/show TRs in a table keeping zebra striping

Tags: html, css, zebra-striping

I have a table which is zebra-striped:

```
tr:nth-child(even)
{
    background-color: red;
}
tr:nth-child(odd)
{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

I want to show/hide its rows, keeping the table striped (recolored from a changed row to the last one). I see 2 ways to do this:

1. Create an invisible table and move `<TR>`s with jQuery `after()` to/from it. I've tested detaching and it works (the table is being recolored on detaching), but inserting the detached (to nowhere) rows doesn't, so moving rows to another table should help, I guess.
2. Call jQuery `toggle()` along with creating/removing invisible `<TR>` right after the one we are toggling.

Which one is better? Maybe, there is even a better way?

Regards,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CSS's `:nth-child` selector selects an element based on its **index among its siblings**. It does not take the visibility (or other selectors) of an element into account.

Instead of adding/removing rows using jQuery, just add/remove class names: http://jsfiddle.net/rTER4/

```
var $allRows = $('tr:visible');
var $oddRows = $allRows.filter(':odd');
var $evenRows = $allRows.filter(':even');

// Remove old classes, then add new ones.
$oddRows.removeClass('even').addClass('odd');
$evenRows.removeClass('odd').addClass('even');

/* CSS */
tr.even { background-color: red; }
tr.odd  { background-color: blue;}
```

Comment: My answer would not differ significantly from this one. I would accept this as an answer if I was the op.

Comment: I added a button functionality to it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rTER4/15/) so newbies like me don't have to research for too long how to add it! it also works with `fadeOut()` or other animations because it waits until the animations are done.